# Flash a message with JQuery, similar to rails flash or connect-flash in node

Tags: jquery, node.js

I am flashing messages to the client from the server using connect-flash in my node.js app. Similar to how you can flash messages in Rails apps.

I need to have this same sort of dynamic message flashing but on the client side using jQuery.

I think the only way is to save a message in a cookie, then redirect and on page load read from the cookie to add the message to the page and delete the cookie.

Is there a plugin that will do this?

Some requirements are that I can flash info and error messages.

- make ajax call to delete an item
- set cookie with success messsage
- redirect to another page that shows the message.

Answer (score 1):

You could just add a listener to the ajax calls. Using cookies will be somewhat messy and is only needed when you need persistence across page loads.

```
<script>
    var flashHandler = $('#flashes');

    flashHandler.on('flash', function(event, message){
        var flash = $('<div class="flash">');
        flash.text(message);
        flash.on('click', function(){
            $(this).remove();
            });
        $(this).append(flash);
    });

    $.ajax('/test',{
        'success' : function(){
            flashHandler.trigger('flash', ['Eureka!']);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why not create the messages server-side via the session and print into the template if you are redirecting?

Comment: because it's the result of an ajax call.

Comment: If you really need it across page loads then you probably want it as part of  state you are preserving on the server.  In which case you'd send the ajax message again to any new page load.